Yookassa: TypeError at /api/registryYoo/__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowed_methods'
Не получается создать ссылку на платеж на платформе yookassa.
Создал yooMoney.py в котором создаю платеж:
import yookassa

from yookassa import Payment, Configuration
import uuid

def yooMoneyPay(amount, finiteUrl, ShopId, SecretKey):
    Configuration.account_id = ShopId
    Configuration.secret_key = SecretKey
    id_key = str(uuid.uuid4())

payment = Payment.create({
    "amount": {
        "value": str(amount),
        "currency": "RUB"
    },
    "confirmation": {
        "type": "redirect",
        "return_url": f'https://{finiteUrl}/#/success'
    },
    "capture": True,
    "description": "Заказ №1"
}, id_key)

return payment.confirmation.confirmation_url

Во views.py у меня API которое должно вернуть url на оплату:
@api_view(['GET'])
def registryYoo (request):
    finiteUrl = os.environ.get('CURRENT_ENVIRONMENT')
    ShopId = os.environ.get('YOOKASSA_SHOP_ID')
    SecretKey = os.environ.get('YOOKASSA_SECRET_KEY')
    cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
    sql = 'select * from dbo.payment_amount where id=1 '
    cursor.execute(sql)
    data = cursor.fetchall()
    amount=data[0][0]
    amount=int(amount)
    cursor.close()
    p_url= yooMoneyPay(amount, finiteUrl, ShopId, SecretKey)
    print(p_url)

return JsonResponse({'p_url': p_url})

Но при вызове получаю ошибку
TypeError at /api/registryYoo/__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowed_methods'

В чем может быть проблема ? Библиотеки обновлены до последней версии, переменные из окружения заполняются.
стек трейс ошибки:
GET http://beta.vrk.ru/api/registryYoo/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'T', "TypeError "... is not valid JSON


Полный стек-трейс ошибки - в вопрос. А не ваш частичный пересказ.

Попробуйте обновить библиотеки requests и urllib3: pip3 install -U requests urllib3

Библиотеки обновлял, нет эффекта

А точно в этом окружении обновляли, из которого запускаете? Попробуйте из вашего скрипта напечатать версии всех этих библиотек и проверить, что они действительно свежие подхватываются.
